# SQL Prevent Duplicate INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a script that I have setup a CRON for that is getting values from a 3rd party server via JSON (cURL)

Right now every time the cron runs it will INSERT a completely new record. Causing duplicates, and resulting me in manually removing the dups.

How would I go about preventing duplicates, and only update the information that is either missing, or different from the $var values?

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

### IF new value is NOT old value use old value else use new value;

```
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE record NOT LIKE record=? ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows !== 1) {
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                        INSERT INTO members (
                                                            start_date
                                                            )

                                        VALUES (?)")) 

        {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('s',$repStartDate);

    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');}
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Read [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: updated my OP for a revised question on INSERT on Dup and my attempt? @Strawberry

Comment: @Saty I have updated my OP. Mind looking at it to see if I am doing ti correctly?

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean UPDATE query ? are you talking about `UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;`

Comment: @Strawberry It is not clearly stated in the documentation 
 
What do I do with `UPDATE c=c+1;`

Comment: how do I do IF new value is less than old value use old value else use new value; \

Comment: @Saty 
INSERT INTO xxx(id,val) SELECT a,b FROM yyyy ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val = VALUES(val)

Taking value that will be inserted with VALUES() only works with INSERT INTO .... VALUES (...), ...

Comment: @Strawberry 
INSERT INTO xxx(id,val) SELECT a,b FROM yyyy ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val = VALUES(val)

Taking value that will be inserted with VALUES() only works with INSERT INTO .... VALUES (...), ...

Comment: @Strawberry notworking.

Comment: "IF new value is NOT old value use old value else use new value;"

This statement is logically identical to "use old value".

Comment: Should be expressed like this: `IF old value is NOT new value use new value else use old value`; @Strawberry

Comment: That statement is logically identical to "use new value"

Comment: *facepalm* All I want to do is update the old information if new is not the same as old.. @Strawberry

Comment: Levi, forget about this 'if x is not y' rubbish. You just want to update the old information. Period.

Comment: Yes that is correct. @Strawberry

Comment: It's important to describe WHY you consider 2 records to be duplicates of each other. We have to know which identical field values make an entry a duplicate. Is it because "title" of one record = "title" of second record? Which fields must MATCH in order to be a duplicate. We will have to "teach" mysql those rules to understand your human concept of a duplicate. mysql knows no such concept by default.

Comment: okay, I understand that. How would I 'teach' mysql which keys to verify as a primary key then only update the row where the values are 'old' data as the json data will be consider 'new' and then insert a new row if it doesn't exist ? @maxhb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing another if statement to check if a unique value existed from incoming and the existing db value existed and leaving it blank to prevent it from importing duplicates. I also wrote a separate file to update where values differentiate between what I am receiving as (new) and what is in the database (old) which actually worked out great for my application.

Here is my answer for anyone else that runs into this issue :)

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_keys=?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$varvalues);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('');

            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) { 
                echo 'shits broke'; }
            }
        } 
        else { if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                            INSERT INTO table (column_keys)
                                            VALUES (?)")) // you will need a ? per column seperate by a , (?,?,?...?)

            { $insert_stmt->bind_param('s',
                                    $varvalues
                                    ); // you will also need to bind a 's' (string) 'i' for num, etc per $var value.

        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) { echo 'shits broke';} //lol 
            }
    }
    }
```

Also a simple error reporting trick I stumbled upon that helped me clean up a few things I overlooked. Just place it at the top of the file, or above you want to debug ;)

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 3):

If you **don't want to update** when the record exists then you can use `Insert Ignore` like below.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM visit;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO visit (user_id, total_visit) VALUES (32, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO visit (user_id, total_visit) VALUES (32, 1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM visit;
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | user_id | total_visit |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |      32 | 1           |
+----+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you **want to update** when the record exists then you can use `On Duplicate Key Update` like below.

```
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO visit (user_id, total_visit) VALUES (32, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_visit = total_visit + VALUES(total_visit);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM visit;
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | user_id | total_visit |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |      32 | 1           |
+----+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO visit (user_id, total_visit) VALUES (32, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_visit = total_visit + VALUES(total_visit);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM visit;
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | user_id | total_visit |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |      32 | 2           |
+----+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[FULL EXAMPLE is here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ojlc/insert-a-new-record-with-insert-ignore-otherwise-update-with-on-duplicate-key)

Comment: I have updated my OP to ask the preferred method and why

Comment: You have to refactor your code. Also you should avoid making major updates to your original question cos you're making answers and comments redundant to curremt state!

Answer (score 1):

Use replace instead of insert:

```
REPLACE INTO members (...) VALUES (...)
```

This will create a new row (like insert) if it's new data and will update existing data if the row is a duplicate of an table existing entry.

Duplicates are found by looking at primary key field and unique keys. So if your data data is a dupliacte when e.g. the username matches then make username a unique index or your primary key.

Further documentation can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

P.S.: INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is a valid solution, too.

Comment: I have updated my OP to ask the preferred method and why @maxhb

Comment: Using your method results in Duplicates

Comment: As i wrote: This will NOT produce duplicates IF you have ALL fields that make up a duplicate defined as primary key or unique key. You have to "tell" mysql what makes two rows duplicates.

Comment: I will update my OP with my current code without the missing values. If you can edit your answer to show me visually i am not underrstanding what you're saying...

Comment: To create an index over the name column use this sql statement: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nameIndex ON members (name(255));

Comment: I would do that above my insert statement or after? And do I place this song statement in my first query prep_stmt or insert_stmt? or in myadmin ? @maxhb

Comment: You'll only have to execute this statement ONE TIME. It modifies the table. You can do it via php or by using phpmyadmin or whatever interface you use.

Comment: the column that I want to do is `record` on the `members` table. I tried to do it, and it kicked an error. what do i have to type exactly ? @maxhb

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what part of the problem this minimal example fails to address:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,constant CHAR(1) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'a');

INSERT INTO my_table (id,constant) VALUES(1,'b') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE constant = VALUES(constant);

INSERT INTO my_table (id,constant) VALUES(4,'a') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE constant = VALUES(constant);


SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+----------+
| id | constant |
+----+----------+
|  1 | b        |
|  2 | b        |
|  3 | a        |
|  4 | a        |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: ditched the NOT NULL (redundant next to pk) ... ie it cant be null. Mainly trying to get Copy Editor points. Nothing else :)

Comment: @Levi this seems to be a nice answer